# Android ListView setTypeFace and setBackgroundDrawable

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView with an OnItemClickListener where I'm setting the background to indicate the row has been selected

```
itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {

        String item = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
        boolean itemSelected = selectedItems.contains(item);

        if (!itemSelected) {
            selectedItems.add(item);
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.listitem_selected));
        } else {
            selectedItems.remove(item);
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        }
    });
```

If I use a default adapter for my ListView, the ListView row is properly highlighted

```
ArrayList<String> listOfItems = new ArrayList<String>();

....
final ArrayAdapter<String> itemAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, listOfItems);
```

If I use a custom adapter that extends ArrayAdapter so that I can set the font of the TextView to a custom font, the font gets set correctly but the background highlighting no longer works. Any ideas?

```
public class ListItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<String> values;

    public ListItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text1);

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/font-file.otf"); 
        textView.setTypeface(tf);
        textView.setText(values.get(position));
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: did u try setting background color for selected item?

Comment: Why don't you use xml selector to change ListView item state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It worked forme. it might help u too.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.text1);

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/font-file.otf"); 
    textView.setTypeface(tf);
    textView.setText(values.get(position));

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {              
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            arg0.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.<background>);                    
        }
    });
    return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set rowView backgroung in getView() method